# Unable to log in to the django admin page due to django-social-auth backends enabled

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have used `django-social-auth` in my project to enable the user to sign in using different social websites like twitter or facebook. For that I have to enable different authentication backends in `settings.py` like this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
)
```

By enabling these backends I can not login to django admin page. Where an occurs saying that username of password not correct for a staff user.

I have disabled these backends then admin page is working but I am not able to achieve the functionality of sign in using different social websites. Please help me out in this problem. All the suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` to this list:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
)
```

when no `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` is specified, backends list defaults to sole [ModelBackend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend)

Comment: then you can accept the answer ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow